# Directory Getfiles not working as I expected

Tags: c#, windows

I am using express VS-2015.I have an  folderbrowser control,textbox1 and button control.
I need to retrieve multiple file type and show it on listbox.I am wondering what is wrong in my code.It is not showing any error but not showing any files, despite of file type present in a folder.any suggestion.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();            
            folderBrowserDlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;            
            DialogResult dlgResult = folderBrowserDlg.ShowDialog();
            if (dlgResult.Equals(DialogResult.OK))
            {               
                textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDlg.SelectedPath;                
                Environment.SpecialFolder rootFolder = folderBrowserDlg.RootFolder;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
            {
                //notification to user
                return;
            }           
            string[] extensions = { ".xml", ".ddg" };
            string[] dizin = Directory.GetFiles(textBox1.Text, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                .Where(f => extensions.Contains(new FileInfo(f).Extension.ToLower())).ToArray();
            listBox1.Items.AddRange(dizin);
        }
```

Comment: There is nothing that to me is obviously wrong with the code. You just need to debug the code. Start by breaking the individual pieces down: look at the result of the `GetFiles()` method itself, make sure the files you expect are actually in the returned array. Then execute the `.Where().ToArray()` portion, with a breakpoint in your lambda; use the debugger's immediate window to evaluate the expressions in the lambda individually, and verify they are doing what you want. FWIW, you should be using `Path.GetFileExtension()`, not the `FileInfo` class (`FileInfo` is not wrong, just less efficient)

Comment: Is it Path.GetExtension() i don't find Path.GetFileExtension() method

Comment: Yes, sorry. I was conflating `GetFileName()` with `GetExtension()`